# Serving one static file with nginx and auth_request

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to server a static file for a location. It's returning 404 and I don't know why.
Here is my config (censored a bit)

```
        root /home/git/website/prod/;

        location = /login {
                index login.html;
        }

        location / {
                auth_request /auth;
                try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
        }

        location = /auth {
                internal;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth/logged_in;
                proxy_pass_request_body off;
                proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
                proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        }


        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }
```

When I try to access /login it returns 404. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your login.html is in `root` folder (/home/git/website/prod/), you could probably use:

```
location = /login {
    try_files /login.html =404;
}
```

Or replace `=404` with `/index.html`. That part is basically telling nginx what to try if `/login.html` is not found on the server.